# echo with sweetalert not working

Tags: sweetalert

I am trying to echo a alert/notification box. This one is working fine -

```
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("Record successfully added in database")';
echo '</script>';
```

But I want to give timing for disappear the box after 2 seconds. I have no idea how to do it. I found through sweetalert it is possible. So I did like this -

```
echo '<script src="sweetalert/lib/sweet-alert.min.js">';
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sweetalert/lib/sweet-alert.css">';
echo 'swal({   title: "Record added successfully!",   
               text: "I will close  in 2 seconds.",   
                timer: 2000 
       });';
echo '</script>';
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 13):

I also faced same problem, when I used: 
   **`echo '<script> swal("....");</script>';`** only...

After one and half day of try, I overcome to this issue, as mention below:

```
<?php
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
  echo 'setTimeout(function () { swal("WOW!","Message!","success");';
  echo '}, 1000);</script>';
?>
```

**HOPE it will help you and others too...**

Comment: Hi Sazz, thanks for your reply but this solution not working. As per my understanding "swal" will not work with  "javasrcipt". "sweetalert.js" is required.

Comment: Its working code dude... And yes ofcourse, you should have sweet-alert.min.js with sweet-alert.css in your project.

Comment: @SHAZ :- I had same problem but i fixed it by the help of you.but i want one more option href after getting this alert how to redirect it to other page after press ok .

Comment: I am trying to use sweet alert when `php` script is successful but there is no alert.Please if you could explain how can i include the `js` file and the `css` file in the `php` script?

Comment: @platanas20,  you just simply include **css** in head section and **js** in **php** part like: `<?php echo '<script scr="sweetalret-min.js"></script>'; echo '<script type="text/javascript">'; /* write alert code here */ </script>'; ?>`


If you still face problem, please show your code.

Comment: I have no results.I use this in the `head` of php file `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/sweetalert.css">` and I use this for echo `echo '<script scr="js/sweetalert-min.js"></script>'; 
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';  
        echo 'setTimeout(function () { swal("GREAT!","Records Added!","success");';
        echo '}, 1000);</script>';`

Comment: This should be the correct answer. It worked for many including me. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 1):

I had no problem typing the library to the top of the file like this :

```html
    <html>
<head><title></title>
 <script src="sweet/sweetalert.min.js"></script> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sweet/sweetalert.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sweet/facebook.css">
</head>
<body>
```

then i opened the php code

```
<?php include ('conexion.php'); .....
echo "<script language = javascript>
                swal({  title: 'Información',
                 text: 'Se ha enviado su petición!',  
                type: 'success',    
                showCancelButton: false,   
                closeOnConfirm: false,   
                confirmButtonText: 'Aceptar', 
                showLoaderOnConfirm: true, }, 
                function(){   
                    setTimeout(function(){     
                        location = 'Frm.php';  
                    });
                     });
            </script>";
```

and all is working well.
Regards!

Answer (score 1):

Just call the custom javascript function that includes the sweet alert from php echo as given below:

```
<header>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="....'path to ur sweet alert.css'">
<script type="text/javascript" src="....'path to ur sweetalert.js'"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function myFn(){
        swal({ 
              title: "Success",
              text: "Thank you for contacting us. We will get back to you soon!",
              type: "success" 
        },
             function(){
                //event to perform on click of ok button of sweetalert
        });
}
</script>

</header>


<?php
   echo '<script type="text/javascript">
       myFn();
      </script>';
?>
```

//Hope this will work for you.. as it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I was having same problem. Later, I used this silly method haha:

```
$swal='swal';
echo '<script>'.$swal.'("Error!", "Something Went Wrong!", "error");</script>';
```

So, You may try a similar thing maybe.

Like:

```
$swal='swal';
echo '.$swal.'({   title: "Record added successfully!",   
               text: "I will close  in 2 seconds.",   
                timer: 2000 
       });';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>
        var swaltitle,swaltext,swallink,swaltype,swallocation,confirmButtonText;
        function showSwal()
        {
            swal({
                  title: swaltitle,
                  text: swaltext,
                  type:swaltype,
                  showCancelButton: false,
                  confirmButtonText:confirmButtonText,
                  timer: 3000
                }).then(
                function () 
                {
                    window.location.href=swallocation;
                },
                function (dismiss)
                {
                    if (dismiss === 'timer') 
                    {
                      window.location.href=swallocation;
                    }
                }
            )
        }
        </script>
    </head>
<body onload="showSwal()">
```

And then you can set the value of all swal varibles by php echo and also do not forget to include CSS and JS link.

Something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                            swaltitle="Success";
                            swaltype="success";
                            swaltext="your message";
                            swallocation="xyz?id="+<?php echo $order_id?>;
                            confirmButtonText="Proceed";
                            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> - PHP Ver.7.2.33.
> - Sweet Alert 2 Ver.10.0.2.

I was getting the same error.

Solution that was good for me, dont use **' '** when echoing a Sweet Alert, try replacing those **' '** whit **" "**

Example:

```
               echo "<script>
           
                Swal.fire({
                     icon: 'error',
                     title: 'Oops...',
                     text: '¡El usuario no debe ir en blanco o llevar caracteres especiales!',
                     showConfirmButton: true,
                     confirmButtonText:'Cerrar ',
                     closeOnConfirm: false

                     })

                 </script>";
```

[errors when using ' ' echoing the Sweet Alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Pyr0.png)

[Everything clear while using " " echoing the Sweet Alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgoxU.png)