# sweet alert function with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have this script that works fine with the normal alert. However I want to replace with swal function

```
if ($res) {
  echo'<script>';
  echo'alert("success")';
  echo'</script>';
}
```

so I have changed the code to

```
if ($res) {
  echo'<script>';
  echo'swal("success")';
  echo'</script>';
}
```

But it doesnt work
i want to achieve same output as this demo

```
$('.demo4').on('click', function() {
  swal('Good job!', 'You clicked the button!', 'success');
});
```

Comment: My assumption is your 'swal()' function requires a library? If thats the case you will have to include before calling the function

Comment: @JParkinson1991 `<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>`

Comment: If not already included in your page you will have to echo that out when you call swal

Comment: The library was included already.but this has solved my issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/28930518/7276718

Answer (score 1):

```
<head>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/6.10.2/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
```